# the set $U =\{(x,-y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x=0,1,-1\text{ and }y \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is which of the following statement is True?

Tags: general-topology

In $\mathbb{R}^2$  with  usual topology, the set $U =\{(x,-y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x=0,1,-1 \text{ and }  y \in \mathbb{N}\}$  is
which of the following statement is True ?

a) neither  closed nor bounded

b)closed but not bounded

c)bounded but not closed

d)closed and bounded

I thinks it will be bounded but not closed because $(x,-y)$ is  an open set that is option c) will be true

Is its  True ?

any hints/solution will apprecaited

thanks u

Comment: What does “$(x,-y)$ is an open set mean”? After all, $(x,-y)$ is a *point* not a set.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos  any Hints ??

Comment: The way you're asking this question made me check several of your previous questions on mathstack. It looks like you just post the problems without making any attempts of acquainting yourself with the definitions and showing what have you tried. I'm sorry to sound rude but it's not the way math is learned.

Comment: ya u  r right   im trying  my best  next time @Mihail

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Surely it is not bounded since $(0,-1)$ , $(0,-2)$ , $(0,-3)$ , $(0,-4)$ , ... belong to the set. Also the set is closed since the minimum distance between any two distinct members of $U$ is at least 1.

Comment: ,,,how minimum distance 1 implies   closed set ?? im not getting this ???

Comment: Then if the terms of a sequence fall near their limit closer than the distance of 1 they must urgently be the limit itself

Comment: In fact after a while the terms of the convergent sequence become equal to their limit

Comment: thanks u  @Mostafa

Comment: You're welcome. Hope it help...